# Acer laptop won't power off

Tags: laptop, power-supply, shutdown

I have an Acer E5 575G running Windows 10.  After using the laptop for less than about 3 hours it will shutdown normally (LED turns off).
If I use it for more than about 3 hours when I shutdown Windows the laptop does not power off (LED stays on).  To power off I must hold down the power button for about 10 seconds and then it powers off.
Has anyone had this problem and found a solution?  Also, after about 3 hours use, the restart button does not restart the laptop it shuts it down.
Could this be a capacitor problem?

Comment: Try first to separate possible problems, if it hardware or software based. I suggest you to download live LinuxMint CD and watch some youtube video on laptop for more than 3 hours then try to shutdown, if laptop will be turned off as it should then an issue is software.

Comment: I have done a fresh install of Windows 10 and the problem persists.  This is most likely a hardware issue.  But I will try Linux.

Comment: I tried to isolate the problem by installing and running Linux Mint and I had no problem.  Linux shut down just fine.  This is obviously a Windows 10 issue.  Has anyone else had this problem with Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 likes to update itself very often (that might prevent shutdown). Check in settings if Windows update allowed to share updates with other computers on internet. Check power options ("Choose what power button do") and make sure there set appropriate for your use case settings. Check with ProcessExplorer (running as administrator) very active processes before you trying to shut it down, if it is Trusted(?)Installer then it can hold off computer from power off. Don't forget that viruses can do the same by intercepting core's API. Try Windows in safe mode for more than 3 hours.